# Add column to listbox in Axapta 3.0 X++

Tags: axapta, x++

Can someone please provide some x++ code examples on how to add columns to a ListBox on a Form?

Additionally, some x++ code examples of how to add data to each new column in the ListBox.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is currently not a good fit for the stack overflow format. Try some research on your own (the Google results for "[Dynamics ax listbox](https://www.google.de/search?q=dynamics+ax+listbox)" might be a good place to start) and then come back with some code and a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this [post](http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.axapta.programming/2008-04/00064/RE-ListBox-control-and-extra-rows.html). You can can add rows but not columns.

Add a listbox to your design, no databinding at all.
Set property autodeclaration to yes.
In `init` on your form add the new elements to your listbox:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    yourListBox.add("Item 1");
    yourListBox.add("Item 2");
}
```

See the `Tutorial_TableDescription` form.

Also, if you have the cross reference available, you can search for the use of the class starting at the System Documentation\Classes\FormListBoxControl.

If possible avoid the use of listboxes, use grids on temporary tables or similar. Listbox controls are not available in AX7.